# Issues with mysql command in bash script

Tags: mysql, bash, variables

I'm really struggling with a bash command, trying to launch a mysql query :

```
output=$(mysql --user=root --password="$password" -s --execute 'grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by "$zabbix_pwd";')
```

The statement above does not work, because $zabbix_pwd is not take as a variable, as it should...

Any idea on how to rewrite this statement would be very helpful.

Cheers,

Raj.

Comment: Read about single vs. double quotes in Bash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your escaping is wrong. Please try this :

```
output=$(mysql --user=root --password="$password" -s --execute "grant all privileges on zabbix.* to zabbix@localhost identified by \"$zabbix_pwd\";")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: It does ! Thanks a lot for taking time in helping me :-)